# How to open a dialog from Quick settings Tile?

Tags: android, android-app-quick-setting

I am developing an app for Quick settings Tile. I want to open a layout or a custom dialog when user click on the tile, whichever is a good option. Assume [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-custom-alertdialog-in-android/) as a custom dialog. I tried many examples, but I got no luck!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to **@Override** method of Tile service.

```
@Override
public void onClick() {
    super.onClick();
    Tile tile = getQsTile();
    switch (tile.getState()) {
        case Tile.STATE_INACTIVE:
            // write code for start service or open activity according to your prefrrance 
            StaticUtils.closeNotificationTopPanel(this);
            tile.setLabel(getString(R.string.service_running));
            updateTileState(Tile.STATE_ACTIVE);
            break;
        case Tile.STATE_ACTIVE:
            updateTileState(Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
            break;
        default:
            updateTileState(Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
            break;
    }
}
```

- when you Click of tile service button you have to close the notification panel below code will help for that.

  ```
  public static void closeNotificationTopPanel(Context context) {
     Intent closeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
     context.sendBroadcast(closeIntent);
  }
  ```
- below method will help you to change the tile state and name of a button according to state.

  ```
   private void updateTileState(int state) {
       Tile tile = getQsTile();
       if (tile != null) {
           tile.setState(state);
           Icon icon = tile.getIcon();
           switch (state) {
               case Tile.STATE_ACTIVE:
                   icon.setTint(Color.WHITE);
                   break;
               case Tile.STATE_INACTIVE:
               case Tile.STATE_UNAVAILABLE:
               default:
                   icon.setTint(Color.GRAY);
                   break;
           }
           tile.updateTile();
       }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use this link**: http://wintechtutorials.com/blog/android-customize-quick-setting-tiles-7-0-nougat/

Here in this link they use default Alert dialog. Try to create custom dialog as per need. Hope this will work for you.